# Android trying to create a simple "empty database"-function, throws NPE

Tags: android, database

I am expanding my application with a neat "delete all"-function in my Preferences. 
What i want from it? Just to, drop the table, delete all inputs... But no... It just gives me an NPE.

And now, i am really clueless...

Prefs.java

```
    Preference wipeDatabase = findPreference("wipeDatabase");
wipeDatabase.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Prefs.this);
        builder.setMessage("YOU SURE!??!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    mDbHelper.deleteAll(); // <-- This is the function.

                }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return false;

    }
});
```

And the function explained in databasehelper.

```
    public void deleteAll() {
    SQLiteDatabase dB = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dB.execSQL("DROP TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE);
}
```

But, it throws an NPE...
I've also tried with:

```
dB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,null,null);
```

But with same result... What am i doing WRONG!? :(

**SOLUTION**

Prefs.java

```
mDbHelper.deleteDatabase(getBaseContext()); // <-- i used this.
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public boolean deleteDatabase(Context context) {
    return context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not deleting the database instead?
It will be recreated next time you open it.

```
public boolean deleteDatabase(Context context) {
    return context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

It will return false if, for whatever reason, it couldn't delete it.

Comment: Glad it worked, that's also what I'm doing. I have a very complex schema in the database, and having to delete all the tables would be a pain, with the risk of missing some of them. Deleting a db and recreating it is so quick in Android, it simplifies the code a lot.

Comment: I just thought it would be, simplier to just delete all rows, and save the database... It would be less timeconsuming... But i guess i was wrong :)

Comment: No you're probably right, but we're talking milliseconds here :)

Comment: @Guillaume Is there a common reason for this to fail? All I get when using `deleteDatabase()` is false. No exceptions or permission errors what so ever.